# How to integrate spinner with no cement background in android

Tags: java, android, xml

Need to remove the spinner background color but want to display the rectangle drop down mark...can any one please help me..

Comment: What things have you tried?

Comment: Here's a nive tutorial on how to change the design of the spinner - http://www.gersic.com/blog.php?id=57

Comment: change bg for spinner in xml, if you are looking for more customizatio then create theme for your application..http://jgilfelt.github.io/android-actionbarstylegenerator/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I used a 9-patch picture to change spinner background. How about this?

```
<Spinner
     android:id="@+id/spinner"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:background="@drawable/spinner_bg"/>
```

spinner_bg:

[image: 9-patch picture]

Comment: @Piyush Gupta very pleased, once more :)

Comment: @Piyush Gupta I worked with java programming language for almost two years, and then delved into the study of an android, on the current job have worked as android developer half of the year. I'm sorry, I'm not very good at English :)

Comment: @Lia...I already used this thing but the spinner items are not visible in that box...